# Handlebars non-block expression helper that can use its parameter name string as well as its value lookup in context

Tags: handlebars.js

I want my own expression helper to return an XML attr=value when used in my template, like so:

```
{{attr foo}}
```

and the output would be:

```
foo="fooval"
```

Another words, if foo is defined in the current context as the string "fooval", I want my helper (which assumes the XML attrname is the same string for both the key and its value lookup) to use both the literal "foo" string and its looked-up value "fooval" to substitute this in its place.

I also wouldn't mind using an 'empty tag' effect block helper, but that doesn't seem to be valid syntax (and I definitely do not want to have to always have a separate {{/attr}} for something I would inline so often:

```
{{! A block helper would work if it could look like this}}
{{#attr foo/}}
{{! and not this}}
{{#attr foo}}{{/attr}}
```

How can my simple expression helper know that it was called with the parameter string "foo", in addition to then looking up "foo in the current context to get "fooval"?

Comment: I would use the string of the key and pass that to the helper so that it can print the key and then do a lookup on the data context with the key. See this example: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/of8dgw9z/ However, I feel I should state this does not seem like a worthwhile helper to me.

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out. The reason it is so useful for my terseness needs is b/c it also serves as a conditional effect, so nothing is generated if the lookup were to fail or be false which I currently am using a wordy block #if to do: {{#if foo}}foo={{foo}}{{/if}}